# Enable/Disable dropdown on radio button select

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I have modal popup window which open on button click for each row in data table. On modal window I have 4 dropdowns and out of these I want one dropdown to be disabled for every row data. When user selects the radio button value as "Yes" it should be enabled.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  var $checkBox = $('.check');

  $checkBox.on('change', function(e) {
    //get the previous element to us, which is the select
    var $select = $(this).prev();
    
    if (this.checked) {
      $select.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
                       <label>Action Taken:</label>
                       <input type="radio" class="check" id="check" name="check" value="Yes">Yes
                       <input type="radio" class="check" id="check" name="check" value="Yes">No
                      <select name="action" id="action" class="form-control" disabled>
                         <option value="">Select Action</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                      </select>     
                        
                    </div>
```

If I am adding the radio buttons after select tag its's working for one row, but after submit when I am selecting second row data it stops working then I have to refresh page again, but I want radio button selection before the select tag also it should work for each row. Can someone help me out what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues here, and each need to be corrected for your code to work properly:

1. The 'No' checkbox has a value of 'Yes'. This needs to be changed in order for your JS to determine which box has been checked.
2. `.action` is a class selector, yet the select has that `id`. As your question suggests there may be multiple clones of this HTML, remove the `id` on the `select` and use the `class` instead
3. The `select` is not the `prev()` element to either radio. Fix this by retrieving the `closest()` common parent and `find()` from there.
4. You're repeated the same `id` of `#check` on the radio buttons, when they must be unique. Either change or remove them.

With that corrected, the code works:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.action').prop('disabled', true);

  let $checkBox = $('.check').on('change', e => {
    var $select = $(e.target).closest('.form-group').find('.action');
    $select.prop('disabled', e.target.value !== 'Yes' && e.target.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Action Taken:</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="No" checked />
    No
  </label>

  <select name="action" class="action form-control" disabled>
    <option value="">Select Action</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Action Taken:</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="Yes" />
    Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="check" value="No" checked />
    No
  </label>

  <select name="action" class="action form-control" disabled>
    <option value="">Select Action</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working now...but how I can set default to no for all the other rows..this is working fine for one row data..when I open modal for second row dropdown is enabled

Comment: how can we make the disabled for all rows unless user selects yes

Comment: Add the `checked` attribute to HTML of the 'No' radio buttons. I updated the example in the answer to show you how

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need 2 different values for your radio button , you have `Yes` for both buttons

```
 <input type="radio" class="check"  name="check" value="Yes">Yes
 <input type="radio" class="check"  name="check" value="No">No
```

you can put your radio buttons and select in a parent div and use that parent to get to access to selectbox instead of using `next` , `prev` ... like `<div class="form-group">`

```
$('.check').change(function(){

   let select = $(this).parents('.form-group:first').find('select') ; 

   if( $(this).val() == 'Yes')
        select.attr('disabled' , false );
   else 
        select.attr('disabled' , true );

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ns5g3rqe/